How do I install nginx proxy manager to my raspberry pi with omv installed
I have tried to install nginx on my raspberry pi, but it already had OMV installed, so  OMV took over my NGinx instance and turned it into it's web portal. I looked it up and it said to install NGinx Proxy Manager. I have docker installed, so would I go about by installing NGinx Proxy Manager. Can someone please help me? I'm not very experienced doing this but I want to learn how to code a website. Thank you so much!

This question might be better at https://superuser.com/ ? Since there is nothing related to programming.
